# cfbundleidentifer of "com.domain.app" doesn't exist

Tags: ios

Whenever I try to publish my app through application loader. I get this error saying that `cfbundleidentifier` of `"com.ufo.MyApp"` doesn't exist. I'm using a wildcard app ID, I already made an app in iTunes connect. The bundle ID is my app Id: `com.ufo.MyApp*` and bundle ID suffix is `com.ufo.MyApp`.

My game is using the provisioning profile with `com.ufo.MyApp`. So I don't know what's wrong here? Why doesn't the `cfbundleidentifier` exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the build version (Example 1.0 changes to 1.0.1) for same bundle id.I hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't seem to do anything. May I ask why changing the version would solve this problem?

Comment: Because i was also suffered from this problem